# Trapezoidal approximation error plotting in python

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to code a function that plots the error of the composite trapezoidal rule against the step size.

Obviously this doesn't look to good since i'm just starting to learn these things.

Anyhow i managed to get the plot and everything, but i'm supposed to get a plot with slope 2, so i am in need of help to figure out where i did go wrong.

```
from  scipy import *
from  pylab import *
from matplotlib import *



def f(x):                               #define function to integrate       
    return exp(x)
a=int(input("Integrate from? "))        #input for a
b=int(input("to? "))                    #inpput for b
n=1                                     

def ctrapezoidal(f,a,b,n):              #define the function ctrapezoidal
    h=(b-a)/n                           #assign h
    s=0                                 #clear sum1-value
    for i in range(n):                  #create the sum of the function
        s+=f(a+((i)/n)*(b-a))             #iterate th sum
    I=(h/2)*(f(a)+f(b))+h*s             #the function + the sum
    return (I, h)                            #returns the approximation of         the integral

val=[]                                  #start list 
stepsize=[]
error=[]

while len(val)<=2 or abs(val[-1]-val[-2])>1e-2:   
        I, h=ctrapezoidal(f,a,b,n)
        val.append(I)
        stepsize.append(h) 
        n+=1

for i in range(len(val)):
        error.append(abs(val[i]-(e**b-e**a)))
error=np.array(error)
stepsize=np.array(stepsize)
plt.loglog(stepsize, error, basex=10, basey=10)
plt.grid(True,which="both",ls="steps")
plt.ylabel('error')
plt.xlabel('h')
```